# One morris.js graph with two MYSQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, graph, morris.js

I have these two queries:

```
<?php
$db->query('SELECT
    SUM(amount) AS summe_bez
    FROM acct_in AS t1
    WHERE paid = 1 AND paid_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY MONTH(paid_date)
    ORDER BY paid_date DESC');
$bezahlt = $db->result();

$db->query('SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(i.unit_price*i.quantity)) AS summe_bek,
    o.paid_date
    FROM invoice_items i
    LEFT JOIN acct_out o ON o.id = i.invoice
    WHERE o.paid = 1 AND o.paid_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH AND CURDATE()
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.paid_date)
    ORDER BY o.paid_date DESC
');
$bekommen = $db->result();
?>
```

They return my results fine:

```
<?php print_r($bekommen); ?> Array ( [0] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 12793 [paid_date] => 2015-08-06 ) [1] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 19570 [paid_date] => 2015-07-30 ) [2] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 26913 [paid_date] => 2015-06-18 ) [3] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 10637 [paid_date] => 2015-05-19 ) [4] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 66550 [paid_date] => 2015-04-30 ) )

<?php print_r($bezahlt); ?> Array ( [0] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 23225.00 ) [1] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 45946.69 ) [2] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 15868.79 ) [3] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 11453.20 ) [4] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 3817.10 ) )
```

Now I'd love to graph a morris.js graph with a data-structure like this:

```
{ y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
{ y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
{ y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
{ y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
{ y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
{ y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
{ y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
```

How can I combine these two queries to result in a form morris.js can graph? I tried json_encode but this keeps appending the arrays after each other instead of merging it.

Best,
Chris

Comment: Can you discribe y , a , z?

Comment: array_merge konnen hilfen sie

Comment: y: [paid_date], a: [summe_bez], b: [summe_bek]

Comment: I tried $new = array_merge($bezahlt, $bekommen); but it gives me: Array ( [0] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 23225.00 ) [1] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 45946.69 ) [2] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 15868.79 ) [3] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 11453.20 ) [4] => Array ( [summe_bez] => 3817.10 ) [5] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 12793 [paid_date] => 2015-08-06 ) [6] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 19570 [paid_date] => 2015-07-30 ) [7] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 26913 [paid_date] => 2015-06-18 ) [8] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 10637 [paid_date] => 2015-05-19 ) [9] => Array ( [summe_bek] => 66550 [paid_date] => 2015-04-30 ) )